# pass class method to fsolve

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I have the following code:

```
import scipy.optimize
class demo(object):
  def get_square(self, var):
    return var ** 2 - 4
new = demo()
scipy.optimize.fsolve(new.get_square(), 1)
```

And I got the following error:

```
TypeError: get_square() missing 1 required positional argument: 'var'
```

But get_square() should always have `self` and `self` need not be passed. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually calling the function *before* `fsolve` has a change to do anything; since the call has no arguments this will raise the expected `TypeError`.

You could either remove the call `()` to `new.get_square`:

```
scipy.optimize.fsolve(new.get_square, 1)
```

or, since you aren't actually even using `self` in `get_square`, make it a `@staticmethod`:

```
class demo(object):
  @staticmethod
  def get_square(var):
    return var ** 2 - 4

new = demo()
scipy.optimize.fsolve(new.get_square, 1)
```

Two small notes:

- Use CapWords for class names, that is, `demo -> Demo`.
- If you aren't trying to be portable between Python 2/3, no need to inherit from `object`.

Comment: Thanks! So if I got it right, `function_name()` is a function call and `function_name` only is a reference to a function? If that's the difference I never noticed it before. Always taking parentheses with function names for granted.

Comment: Yes, `()` with a function results in a function call. Glad you've got that worked out now :-)

Comment: I got some further question. Please refer to my update. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan further questions should not be an update to an already existing question, instead, you should ask *a new question*.

Comment: I posted new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071089/different-results-when-passing-function-method-to-equation-solver) and rolled back my update for clarity. Thanks for your suggestion!