# Different results when passing function / method to equation solver

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sympy

This question is a follow-up of previous question [pass class method to fsolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030733/pass-class-method-to-fsolve).

@jim's answer in that question about difference between the function object name and a function call clarified my confusion and solved the problem. However, when I tried similar things in sympy:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

class Demo():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.i = var
    def func(self):
        return self.i ** 2 - 4

x = Symbol('x')
def func(v):
    return v ** 2 - 4
new = Demo(x)
solve(new.func(), x) # This works fine, even as a function call
solve(func(x), x) # This works fine, even as a function call
```

Why do I have different results? (In scipy I need to pass function name to solver while in sympy I need to pass the function call.) Is it because different implementation of the two libraries? In the above example, if I substitute the function call with function name, exception will be raised:

```
File "<ipython-input-26-3554c1f86646>", line 13, in <module>
solve(new.func, x)

File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 817, in solve
f, symbols = (_sympified_list(w) for w in [f, symbols])

File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 817, in <genexpr>
f, symbols = (_sympified_list(w) for w in [f, symbols])

File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\solvers.py", line 808, in _sympified_list
return list(map(sympify, w if iterable(w) else [w]))

File "Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 324, in sympify
raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)

SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '<bound method Demo.func of <__main__.Demo object at 0x0000018A37DA6518>>'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

Comment: You're not passing a function name... You're passing the function return value because you've called the function

Comment: @cricket_007 Seems I'm missing out very basic knowledge about functions... Please see my own answer and let me know if I made it right.

Comment: Looks right. Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the solver is provided parameter `(func(x), x)`, it is equivalent to provide `(x ** 2 - 4, x)`, the first part of which is an expression containing the declared symbol `x`.

However when the parameter list is `(func, x)`, the variable in function definition, `v`, is undefined and does not match that provided as the second argument, which is `x`. This causes exception to be raised.

In the scipy case, returned expression of the function definition has one variable, `var`, to be solved, and can thus work properly.